# Secure Shell (SSH)

Tags: ssh, network-bridge

So, I am learning about SSH and I am wondering if it is possible to make one's computer accessible from another through ssh? I honestly do not know completely how SSH works, so if I need to know more info about it, guidance would be helpful (because I feel everything I have looked at is very vague.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH is a utility that allows you to securely access the command line of a different machine remotely.

One of the easier ways to do this is to install OpenSSH on the machine you are trying to ssh to and then once you have configured it you can access it from another machine. Linux and Mac machines come with the ability to SSH to a machine, if you are trying to SSH from a PC you will need to install something like PuTTY.

This guide is very helpful to set up an SSH system, however you can ignore the part about turning off password authentication if you plan on only accessing it from your home network. If you plan on accessing it from outside of your LAN that is an entirely different rodeo.

[SSH / OpenSSH / Configuring | Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring)

Please read this guide carefully because the instructions are very explicit and I don't feel there is a need to try and summarize something that is as clearly articulated as the above article.

SSH is not a GUI, it is strictly a Command Line Interface (CLI). If you want a GUI you will need to look into Remote Desktop.

Comment: The article is very helpful, thanks a lot. I was able to setup a few servers and clients on the home network.